# Limit of the integral of a continous function with Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, indefinite-integrals

I want to compute $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x e^{t^2}-1 dt$$
I have thought that $f(t)=e^{t^2}-1$ is a continous function because it is composition of continous functions and so I can apply the Weierstrass theorem to bound the function from above and below. But I don't know exactly how I can do this...the Weiestrass theorem in fact states that a maximum and a minimum for a function exist in a closed and bounded interval. How can I can apply this here? Actually I would say
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x min\quad dt\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x e^{t^2}-1 dt\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x max\quad dt  $$
but I don't know how I can motivate this...in which interval can I apply Weierstrass?

Moreover I have also thought that I can simply state that since when $x\to 0$ the lower and upper limits will coincide then I obtain $0$, but I am not so convinced...can you help me?

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=e^{t^2}-1$ is a monotone increasing function, so for $0<x<1$, $$0<e^{t^2}-1<e-1$$ You can also apply Weierstrass by taking the max $M$ and min $m$ of $f$ on the unit interval $[0,1]$ (which are $1$ and $0$, by the way), then $$m\leqslant f(x)\leqslant M$$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, in particular the last inequality holds in every subinterval $[0,x]\subseteq [0,1]$, thus you have $$mx\leqslant \int^x_0e^{t^2}-1dt\leqslant Mx$$

Comment: Ok the fact that this function admits a maximum and a minimum in a bounded interval is something that I have understood...I have not understood how can apply this fact to bound the limit of the integral!

Comment: I've changed the original comment to include Weierstrass and how to bound the integral

Comment: @Alessandro Thanks for the edit of the comment...what I can't understand is: that inequality holds only for $x\leq 1$...can I apply this in my case only because $x\to 0$?

Comment: Well, If you consider a limit $x\rightarrow x_0$ you can treat as if $x$ is arbitrarily close to $x_0$ (because the purpose of the limit is for $x$ to reach $x_0$)

Comment: But can I simply instead say that the limit is zero beacuse for $x$ that goes to $0$ I would have a limit from $0$ to $0$? I mean it is always true that $\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$?

Comment: Yes, but how do you prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\int^x_0f(t)dt$ for a continuous function? By restricting to an interval $[0,x_0]$, so that there are $m,M\in\mathbb R$ such that $m\leqslant f(x)\leqslant M$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$, so $$mx\leqslant\int^x_0f(t)dx\leqslant Mx\rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int^x_0f(t)dt=0$$

Comment: Ah ok! So the fact that it is $0$ is not due by the fact that both the upper and lower limits of the integral become $0$?

Comment: Well, yes. But for a general map $g$ that can be integrated $a\mapsto\int_0^ag(t)dx$ is not necessarily continuous, so it need not be true that $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int^a_0=\int^0_0=0$$so you need to prove that such limit is valid. There are theorems that prove just that under certain conditions, like the dominated convergence theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem .

Comment: Ok well! So it is better to prove that the limit is $0$ using the bound $M$ and $m$ right?

Comment: Yes, or a convergence theorem if you can. In this case, being the function integrated continuous, it's easier to use $M,m$. Monotone convergence, for example, is used with less regular functions (like non continuous, ecc...)

Comment: here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778343/how-can-i-find-limit-of-integral in the first question it is stated that the integral function is always continous...

Comment: Yes, but it is a theorem. If you can use the theorem that $x\mapsto\int^x_0g$ is continuous, then the result follows immediately. I just gave you a solution similar to the one you proposed in your question, where you use that the function is bounded above and below to prove that the integral converges to zero. Then of course there are shorter ways

Comment: Ok it semmed from your last but one comment that is not true that $x\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt$ is not continous...

Comment: yes, it was a mistake. My bad

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help!!